# The SQL view is automatically expanding the splat operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

As I was creating a view I accidentally found out that every splat operator is automatically expanded. For instance with the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    c integer
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,2,3), (10,20,30);

CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * FROM test;
```

The following `SELECT` statements return the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
SELECT * FROM test_view;
```

However if I add a column to the original table:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN x text DEFAULT 'new column';
```

... and issue the same `SELECT` statements as before, when querying the view, the new column gets lost. And indeed I verified the actual definition of my view with the `pg_get_viewdef` function - the splat has been automatically expanded to the columns a, b and c.

Why is it implemented like this and can I prevent that behavior from occurring?

At the moment I'm in a dire need of creating several views to filter the contents of the tables. However, their overall structure may change in the future - new columns may be added and some may get stripped. At this point I would have to update every single view after changing the tables and frankly, I do not like the sound of this.

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: No, you can't do that. This is also not Postgres specific, _every_ DBMS expands the `*` to the list of columns that exist at the time when the view was created. Just put all your view definitions into a script and re-run them any time you change your tables. If you manage your schema migrations with a tool like liquibase you can fully automate this process.